# Knockoutjs - checked radio doesn't call function

Tags: function, knockout.js, radio-button

Is there any way to bind checked radio with function which add new object to my array?

JS

```
ViewModel = function(path) {
    var self = this;

    self.regions = ko.observableArray();

    self.addRegion = function() {
        self.regions.push(new Ticketon.Performance.Region());
    };
}

Region = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.description = ko.observable();
};
```

HTML

```
<label><input type="radio"  name="regionCount" checked="checked"> One region</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="regionCount" data-bind="checked: addRegion"> Two regions</label>
```

This do nothing... When I change **CHECKED** on **CLICK** it works, but when I click more times on the radio, there is more regions in array.

Comment: So where in the two way data binding is `removeRegion` called?

Comment: It is not called in this case. It is irrelevant now.

Comment: But how would the region ever get removed? If you click multiple times you'll just add more and more to the observable array.

Comment: There is another button "erase" in the form. But this is not my question. My question is, how to call function by checked radio? Is it possible? In documentation is only sending value of radio to variable. I know there is way how to make event depended on that variable, but it seems to be quite dirty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `checked` binding stores the value (that you would specify using the `value` attribute) to an observable. It's not expecting a function.

To do what you're intending, you would need to use the `click` binding. If you want to limit or toggle the number of regions, the function would need to perform this logic.

Comment: Thank you, I needed to hear that.